# How to preserve inline query comments in SQLDeveloper Oracle exports?

Tags: sql, oracle, export, comments

When I export query results from SQL Developer to a spreadsheet, I get a separate tab named SQL with the select statement. However, all inline comments (those starting with --) are missing.

Is there a preference or an export method that would preserve these inline comments? Essentially, I would like entire script used to be shown in the SQL tab.

Ver 3.2.09 but can use ver 4, as well.

Comment: I get same results with 4.1.5.  In-line comment is not exported to the query table.  Try posting to the SQLDeveloper forum at https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer

Comment: I've seen spreadsheets produced by others and they do have inline comments in the SQL tab. I don't believe they pasted their query into that tab, so that would mean that there is a preference or something...

Comment: I use 4.1.1, and they do show up for me. How are you exporting? I run my query, right-click the query results, then Export.. using format excel 2003+.

Comment: Update, it is actually working for me on 4.1.5.  I was running query, right-clicking result, export as 2003+.  I must have added comments but not actually re-run query.  But, I've tried several iterations and this does work, the query with the comments are exported as expected.

Comment: Confirming that 4.1.5.21 works for me. So are we to assume this is SQL Version difference and not a Preference? I tried both xls and xlsx in 3.2.09, having luck with neither.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version (18.4), this is working as expected. Note I'm using the the XLSX export option.

[image]

There's no option to control this, you just want to make sure your comment is picked up as part of the sql statement, so before you get to a statement delimiter